# How to generate .mobi file with kindlegen detected as ebook instead of personal file?

Tags: kindlegen

I am trying to generate a .mobi file with kindlegen.

```
kindlegen -c2 myEbook.opf -o myEbook.mobi
```

I compile the ebook and the .mobi file is generated, but when I copy the file to my kindle device, it doesn't appear at the list of books.

If I click in the "All of the content" option in the kindle's device menu, the book appears with the string "Personal".

I read on the internet that I need to change the [PDOC] tag to [EBOK], but I don't know how to do this with kindlegen.

In order to do this, I tried to convert the mobi file (generated with kindlegen) into mobi format with Calibre software and changing the tag.
With this solution, the Kindle device detects correctly the new mobi file as an ebook instead of a personal file but the problem there is that Calibre modifies the CSS format of the original ebook and there are some changes in the final presentation of the ebook.

What can I do in order to generate a mobi file with my CSS style (not calibre style) and detected as an ebook in my Kindle device?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't have error messages from the kindlegen phase, then you're getting a valid mobi file. In the case of a valid mobi file, this Q is probably best suited for the 'superuser' or 'ebooks' stackexchange. Also.. I believe Calibre has a way to use your own CSS.

Comment: http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @Paulb. I didn't know about the existence of these stackexchange places.